# Calling VirtualProtect on a mapped file

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm using the CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile functions to map a file into memory. After a certain point, I call VirtualProtect to change its protection from read-only to read and write. This call fails and GetLastError gives ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Here is a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE fd, md;
    char *addr;
    DWORD old;
    BOOL ok;

    fd = CreateFile("filename", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    md = CreateFileMapping(fd, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 100, NULL);
    addr = MapViewOfFile(md, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 100);
    ok = VirtualProtect(addr, 100, PAGE_READWRITE, &old);
    if (!ok) {
        // we fall into this if block
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        // this outputs "error protecting: 87"
        printf("error protecting: %u\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(addr);
    CloseHandle(md);
    CloseHandle(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I not allowed to call VirtualProtect on a region containing a mapped file?

Comment: Are the previous function returning the expected value? I realize you posted only a snippet ... but make sure you test **ALL** return values from MapViewOfFile, CreateFileMapping, CreateFile, ...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the other functions aren't failing. I've omitted the other error checks for simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start out by creating the view with FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE and protect with PAGE_READONLY.  Now you have no trouble making it PAGE_READWRITE later:

```
addr = MapViewOfFile(md, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 100);
ok = VirtualProtect(addr, 100, PAGE_READONLY, &old);
//...
ok = VirtualProtect(addr, 100, PAGE_READWRITE, &old);
```

Comment: Okay, so I want to call CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile with the maximum access I might need in the future. I'll add another wrinkle: if I wasn't the one who originally opened the file handle, is there a way I can find out what the highest level of access available is on that file handle?

Comment: A FALSE return and GetLastError() tells you, same idea.

Comment: Are you suggesting I try the highest access first and then work my way down to the lowest that doesn't give me an error? I guess that could work, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Comment: Also, in `hostile environment` :-) - before trying to VirtualProtect you could call VirtualQuery and see what was the original memory protection option (AllocationProtect member of MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION structure)

Answer (score 3):

What happens in your code is that `VirtualProtectEx` (invoked by `VirtualProtect` of yours) fails with error **STATUS_SECTION_PROTECTION** (0xC000004E) - *"A view to a section specifies a protection that is incompatible with the protection of the initial view"* and this seems to be what you did indeed by creating a section view with more restrictive protection (FILE_MAP_READ).

This topic doesn't seem to be documented with enough details, so I think you'd better simply follow what Hans suggested.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556(v=vs.85).aspx this should be legal. According to VirtualProtect documentation, the new flags must be compatible with the "VirtualAlloc" flags - if this transfer to the "MapViewOfFile" flags, I'd suspect that you can tighten but not loosen the protection. Try mapping readwrite and changing protection to readonly.