# C++ intercept functions by splicing

Tags: visual-c++

I wanna intercept functions by splicing. That's what i wrote

```
#include <windows.h> 

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); 

WCHAR wch[60]; 
int i; 

typedef LONG    NTSTATUS; 
typedef LONG    KPRIORITY; 

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) ((NTSTATUS)(Status) >= 0) 

#define STATUS_SUCCESS                   ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L) 
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH      ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000004L) 

#define SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation    5 

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING { 
      USHORT        Length; 
      USHORT        MaximumLength; 
      PWSTR         Buffer; 
      } UNICODE_STRING; 

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESSES { 
    ULONG             NextEntryDelta; 
    ULONG             ThreadCount; 
    ULONG             Reserved1[6]; 
    LARGE_INTEGER     CreateTime; 
    LARGE_INTEGER     UserTime; 
    LARGE_INTEGER     KernelTime; 
    UNICODE_STRING    ProcessName; 
    KPRIORITY         BasePriority; 
    ULONG             ProcessId; 
    ULONG             InheritedFromProcessId; 
    ULONG             HandleCount; 
    ULONG             Reserved2[2]; 
//    VM_COUNTERS       VmCounters; 
//    SYSTEM_THREADS    Threads[1]; 
} SYSTEM_PROCESSES, * PSYSTEM_PROCESSES; 

UCHAR bufZwQSI[5];
typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *pWinApiF) (UINT SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation,                                  ULONG SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength); 

pWinApiF lpZwQSI; 

NTSTATUS WINAPI xZwQSI(UINT SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation, ULONG     SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength); 

bool SetSplicingHook(pWinApiF pfnDst, pWinApiF pfnHook, UCHAR buffer[5]) 
{ 
if(IsBadWritePtr(buffer, 5) || IsBadReadPtr(pfnDst, 5)) return false; 
memcpy(buffer, pfnDst, 5);
DWORD old = 0; 
if(!VirtualProtect(pfnDst, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old)) return false;
DWORD offset = (DWORD) pfnHook - (DWORD) pfnDst - 5; 
*(BYTE*)pfnDst = 0xE9;
*(DWORD*)((DWORD)pfnDst+1) = offset; 

if(!VirtualProtect(pfnDst, 5, old, &old)) return false; 
return true; 
} 

void UnsetSplicingHook(pWinApiF pfnDst, UCHAR buffer[5]) 
{ 
    DWORD old = 0; 
    if(!VirtualProtect(pfnDst, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old)) return; 
    memcpy(pfnDst, buffer, 5);
    if(!VirtualProtect(pfnDst, 5, old, &old)) return; 
} 

NTSTATUS WINAPI xZwQSI(UINT SystemInformationClass, PVOID SystemInformation, ULONG     SystemInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength) 
{ 
    wsprintf(wch,L"%d",++i); 
    UnsetSplicingHook(lpZwQSI, bufZwQSI); 
    NTSTATUS ret = lpZwQSI(SystemInformationClass,   SystemInformation, SystemInformationLength, ReturnLength); 
    if(!SetSplicingHook(lpZwQSI, xZwQSI, bufZwQSI)) 
    { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot set hook to ZwQuerySystemInformation", L"Error", MB_OK); 
        ExitProcess(0); 
    } 
    if(ret != STATUS_SUCCESS) 
        return ret; 

    if(SystemInformationClass == SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation) 
    { 
        PSYSTEM_PROCESSES pProcesses = (PSYSTEM_PROCESSES)SystemInformation; 

        memset(pProcesses, 0, sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSES)); 
        pProcesses->NextEntryDelta = 0; 
        pProcesses->ProcessId = 1; 
        pProcesses->ProcessName.Buffer = L"CepbIu 0wn3d u"; 
        pProcesses->ProcessName.Length = 100; 
    } 

    return ret; 
} 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{ 
    wsprintf(wch,L"none"); 
    i=0; 
    *(FARPROC*)&lpZwQSI = GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll"), "ZwQuerySystemInformation"); 
    if(!SetSplicingHook(lpZwQSI, xZwQSI, bufZwQSI)) 
    { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot set hook to ZwQuerySystemInformation", L"Error", MB_OK); 
        ExitProcess(0); 
    } 
    HWND hMainWnd;   
    WCHAR szClassName[] = L"Hide"; 
    MSG msg; 
    WNDCLASSEX wc; 
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(wc);         
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; 
    wc.cbClsExtra     = 0; 
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0; 
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance; 
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); 
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL; 
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName; 
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot register class", L"Error", MB_OK); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    hMainWnd = CreateWindowEx(  
        NULL,szClassName, L"Hide", 
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU, 
        1000, 400, 150, 150, 
        (HWND)NULL, (HMENU)NULL, 
        (HINSTANCE)hInstance, NULL 
    ); 

    if (!hMainWnd) { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Cannot create main window", L"Error", MB_OK); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, nCmdShow); 

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))  { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    } 

    return msg.wParam; 
} 

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{ 
    HDC hDC; 
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
    RECT rect; 
    switch (msg) 
    { 
    case WM_CREATE: 
        SetTimer(hWnd,NULL,500,NULL); 
        return 0; 

    case WM_TIMER: 
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,TRUE); 
        return 0; 

    case WM_PAINT: 
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&rect); 
        DrawText(hDC, wch, -1, &rect, 
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER ); 
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
        return 0; 

    case WM_CLOSE: 
        DestroyWindow(hWnd); 
        return 0; 
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        return 0; 
    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

But it doesnt work,i wanna know where i do a mistake? Tested on Windows 7 and XP.

Comment: What errors are you getting, and what code is producing the error? Like this we can't help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling VirtualProtect on a mapped file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346913/calling-virtualprotect-on-a-mapped-file)

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualProtect` won't give you more access to a mapped page than the access you originally opened it with, and your user account almost certainly doesn't have enough permission to open it with write access anyway.

Comment: How can i fix this? And why debugger says to me that memory patched?

Comment: @Cepblu: Your program doesn't even call `ZwQuerySystemInformation`, so what are you expecting to happen after you hook it?